# Expresión regular no evalua toda la cadena

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Estoy haciendo una pequeña función regular en **Python 3.8**, la cual me debe permitir que la primera letra de la serie de caracteres esté en mayúscula, seguido de más de una letra en minúscula y de permitir guion y guion al piso después del carácter en mayúscula y reemplazar donde hay un espacio por un asterisco, el problema es que le paso una cadena con dos palabras y la **expresión regular** solo me lee una de estas palabras. Tampoco he encontrado el modo de remplazar los espacios en blanco.

```
Expresion = re.compile(r"(?P<Nombre>^[A-Z]{1,1}[a-z_-]{2,10})")
Match = Expresion.search('Mikel Nielsen')

print(Match)
```

De resultado la consola solo me imprime **Mikel** el que busco esl **Mikel Nielsen** ya que las dos palabras son válidas.

Comment: siempre es bueno poner un [mcve] con casos buenos y casos malos, para entender de manera rápida qué estás buscando sin tener que remitirse a una explicación larga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las expresiones regulares son complicadas.

Tu problema es que `search` sólo encuentra una instancia de la expresión que busca. Si deseas encontrar todas las instancias, usa `findall`, que retorna una lista con todo lo que encontro.

Hagamos un ejemplo sencillo: queremos encontrar todas las instancias de bloques de "A" en el string "AA AAA A".

La expresiòn regular es

```
exp = re.compile("[A]+")
g = exp.findall("AA AAA A")
print(g)
```

el resultado es una lista. Cada elemento contiene una instancia del patron buscado:

```
['AA', 'AAA', 'A']
```

Respecto a tu caso en particular, la expresión regular se puede acortar: `{1,1}` es redundante. Por default, los patrones solo calzan una vez.

Los paréntesis también son redundantes en este caso.

Es un error usar "^" en tu caso. Ese operador solo calza al comienzo del string, y tù quieres que el patrón calce en cualquier parte.

Es innecesario ponerle nombre a los patrones, ya que aqui obtienes una lista. Los nombres se usan cuando buscas dos o màs cosas distintas (por ejemplo, quieres sacar el nombre y el telefono).

Resumiendo, el patrón corregido sería

```
exp=re.compile(r"[A-Z][a-z_-]{2,10}")
g=exp.findall("Mike Nielsen")
print(g)
```

que produce

```
['Mike', 'Nielsen']
```